# How to display decimal value in desired format?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( '0.200','999.999')) AS NUM_ FROM DUAL;
```

How to show  0.200 ?

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR( 0.200,'9990.999') AS NUM_ ,  TO_CHAR( 0.200,'9990D999') AS NUM2_ FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0):

According to your example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER( '0.200','999.999'), 'fm0.000') AS NUM_ 
FROM DUAL;
```

You can simplify it like :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.2, 'fm0.000') AS NUM_ 
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

At **individual SQL statement** level:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(.2, 'fm0.000') num FROM DUAL;

NUM
------
0.200

SQL>
```

**In SQL*Plus:**

```
SQL> set numformat 0.999
SQL> SELECT .2 num FROM DUAL;

   NUM
------
 0.200

SQL>
```

I would recommend using **TO_CHAR** with desired **format model** to display the number in your desired format.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR( '0.200','990.999')) AS NUM_
    FROM DUAL
```